# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extents'" when attempting to plot a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I am trying to plot a figure using the following code. I am using [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-beautiful-river-maps-with-python-37c9b5f5b74c) article as a guide. The code is the exact same as the author's code, and I have double checked my code against theirs.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

africa_rivers = gpd.read_file('~/Python/Projects/River Maps/africa/afrivs.shp')
lakes = gpd.read_file('~/Python/Projects/River Maps/ne_10m_lakes/ne_10m_lakes.shp')
country_shapefiles = gpd.read_file('~/Python/Projects/River Maps/ne_10m_admin_0_countries/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp')
africa = country_shapefiles.loc[country_shapefiles['CONTINENT'] == 'Africa'] 
africa_lakes = gpd.sjoin(lakes, africa, op = 'intersects')
africa_lakes = lakes.loc[lakes.index.isin(africa_lakes.index.tolist())]
excluded_rivers = gpd.sjoin(africa_rivers, africa_lakes, op = 'within') 
africa_rivers = africa_rivers.loc[~africa_rivers.index.isin(excluded_rivers.index.tolist())]

lake_victoria = africa_lakes.loc[africa_lakes['name'] == 'Lake Victoria']
funny_features = gpd.sjoin(lake_victoria, africa_rivers, op = 'within')
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor='#FCF6F5FF')
fig.set_size_inches(5,7)
    
lake_victoria.plot(ax = ax, color = 'black', alpha = 0.1)
funny_features.plot(ax = ax, color = 'blue', lw = 0.4, alpha = 1)
    
ax.axis('off')
    
plt.show()
```

The titled error is accompanied by the following error message:

```
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/PopulationDensity/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/plotting.py:681: UserWarning: The GeoDataFrame you are attempting to plot is empty. Nothing has been displayed.   UserWarning,
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/PopulationDensity/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    339                 pass
    340             else:
--> 341                 return printer(obj)
    342             # Finally look for special method names
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/PopulationDensity/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, base64, **kwargs)
    149         FigureCanvasBase(fig)
    150 
--> 151     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    152     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    153     if fmt == 'svg':

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/PopulationDensity/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, pad_inches, bbox_extra_artists, backend, **kwargs)
   2298                 if bbox_inches == "tight":
   2299                     bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(
-> 2300                         renderer, bbox_extra_artists=bbox_extra_artists)
   2301                     if pad_inches is None:
   2302                         pad_inches = rcParams['savefig.pad_inches']

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/PopulationDensity/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in get_tightbbox(self, renderer, bbox_extra_artists)
   1630 
   1631         for a in artists:
-> 1632             bbox = a.get_tightbbox(renderer)
   1633             if bbox is not None and (bbox.width != 0 or bbox.height != 0):
   1634                 bb.append(bbox)

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/PopulationDensity/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in get_tightbbox(self, renderer, call_axes_locator, bbox_extra_artists, for_layout_only)
   4660                 clip_extent = mtransforms.Bbox.intersection(
   4661                     clip_extent, axbbox)
-> 4662                 if np.all(clip_extent.extents == axbbox.extents):
   4663                     # clip extent is inside the Axes bbox so don't check
   4664                     # this artist

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extents'
```

Comment: it looks like the traceback is cut off at the top - did you edit it or is this the whole thing? if so can you include the whole traceback?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Looks like this part got cut off.
`~/opt/anaconda3/envs/PopulationDensity/lib/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/plotting.py:681: UserWarning: The GeoDataFrame you are attempting to plot is empty. Nothing has been displayed.
  UserWarning,`

Comment: rather than posting as a comment, can you update the question to include the full traceback? you should be able to click the "Edit" button at the bottom of your post